# jQuery UI-Datepicker multiple month custom title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Datepicker UI displaying about 12 calendars at once and I would like to customize one common title to all of them.

My idea was to use Jquery and add an element `#ui-datepicker-div` , a DIV with the title. But there is no trigger being fired once the calendar is shown, so I m unable to replace/add/delete HTML code inside the datepicker and neither to add another DIV and place in the same location where datepicker is.

Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **beforeShow** event to do your changes. This event is also fired, when you display the calendars right away.

```
$(yourDatepickerDivOrWhatever).datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(){
        // your changes to the datepicker headline here
    }
});
```

You may also add a **data** attribute to indicate that you have done your changes already on this calendar.

Comment: I think beforeShow draws again all the content inside so this is not solution. I mean that if I replace the content by '' the datepicker is also being shown

Comment: But, one solution was to add / remove one custom class to the element, and so, add an background image with the title